# c# console, about / and % operator (Probably basics)

Tags: c#, console, operators

Sorry if I don't explain this as well as I should...
I've written the code below in a console main.

```
int myint = 0;
while (myint < 100) {
    myint++;
    if ((myint / 16) == 0) {
        Console.WriteLine(myint); }
}
```

Now what I wan't is for it to post multiples of 16 so I changed the ((myint / 16) == 0) to ((myint % 16) ==0) which worked...
My actual question is, when I use ((myint / 16) == 0) why does it write 1-15 to the console?

Comment: while myint value is <16 => myint/16 will be 0. Hence first 0-15 counter is printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

```
(myint / 16) == 0
```

is only true if myint is smaller than 16. So, e.g. 5 / 16 is 0 beacuse you are dividing integers (result is rounded down).

Also, the output starts with 1 since you do

```
myint++
```

before the if / Console.WriteLine and you have myint initialized with 0.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're performing [Integer division](http://approache.com/blog/dividing-integers-in-c-are-evil/). Whatever number less than 16 `(myint / 16)` will yield zero as result which evaluates to `true` so it prints from 1-15.